# Three.js GLTFLoader not working on node server

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

Instead of loading a glb/gltf file from the server by providing a URL to the function:

```
// Instantiate a loader
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

// Load a glTF resource
loader.load(
    // resource URL
    url,
    // called when the resource is loaded
    function ( gltf ) {
      //do something with the loaded file
    },
);
```

I would like to use this loader on my node server instead of on the client, since traversing the geometry to get all materials is easier to do on the server.
But it seems like this loader is meant to work specifically on the client side (not sure) hence once I try to run it on my server I get different errors like:

> TypeError: XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor

Which makes sense since XMLHttprequest is not defined for node. 
But the main problem is how do I make the three.js [FileLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/GLTFLoader) simply load the file by providing a path to a directory on the server instead of doing XMLHttp requests which shouldn't be needed?

Thanks in advance and sorry if the question may not be too clear. First post here on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You can try Node-XHR https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest to patch in XHR to Node.

But you have it local, then you can try `new THREE.GLTFLoader().parse()`